# the width of first column of jQuery dataTable cannot be set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

A checkbox is added to the first column of jQuery dataTable in my project to provide a multi-select function to user. However, its width is uncontrolled which is too large when full screen that i just want it always showing in 45px. I have tried to fix it in jQuery and css, but all fail.

My try:

```
//jQuery
$('.dataTable').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "45", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} ); 

//css
.dataTable > thead > tr > th:first-child {
    width: 45px!important;
}
```

any idea?

Comment: have you tried `{ "width": "45px", "targets": 0 }`; i.e. add px after your value.

Comment: @vijayP sure, nothing happens

Comment: have you tried other option provided on documentation page: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width

Comment: Define your width in percentage, like width: 20%.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in js:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "45px", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

or in css:

```
#datatable td:nth-child(1)
    {
        width: 45px;
    }
```

Comment: what is meaning of  td:nth-child(9)?

Comment: Its by mistake. It is 1

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea?

Yes. You cannot rely on `width`; browsers do not necessarily care to preserve a `width` if other elements shrinks the space or gives more room than required. However, if you define a `min-width`, then you are certain that `width` is set to that value by default :

```css
table.dataTable tbody td:first-child {
  min-width: 45px !important;
}
```